# iptables block port range with single port exception

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I`ve two rules. First blocked all port from range:

> -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --match multiport --dports 200:65535 -j DROP

and second open one in this range:

> -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5901 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

but it doesn`t work. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 6):

IIRC `iptables` rules are order dependent: if the first rule matches, it won't parse any more. Reverse the order and you should achieve what you're trying to do.

*Extension:* it is not always so, some rules (f.e. `-j LOG`) allows the packet processing to go further. But the common `ACCEPT`, `REJECT`, etc. rules aren't. Best if you see iptables as if it were a procedural programming language: rules are tried-to-match and executed in always linearly, in order.

Comment: yes as @shearn89 told, iptables evaluate the rules from top

Comment: This is indeed how it works. If you see it as a procedural language, then custom chains are procedures/functions, which you can call from other rules. There even is a `RETURN` target which you can use to return from a procedure to where it was called from.